# Could using magnetism principles aid us in achieve near speed of light travel

Tags: design-alternative, speed-of-light

Could a vehicle with ferrous properties be passed threw a hollow tube, that had coils spaced out in intervals, and which produced strong magnetic field in the vacuum of space, create speeds close to light speed. Especially if said vehicle had a slight arc of travel allowing it to pass through the magnetic field repeatedly picking up speed with each pass?

Comment: passed **through**...

Comment: "_slight arc_" is doing quite a bit of work there. Have a think about the strength of the centrifugal forces involved when something is travelling in a circle at relativistic velocities, or the mindboggling size of the accelerator needed to reduce those forces to something tolerable.

Comment: Do you mean with current technology, a theoretical possibility, or does a law of physics call it impossible? @Dan W.

Answer (score 5):

So you're proposing a railgun or a circular railgun which is basically nothing else that the [ring shaped accelerators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_accelerator) like we already have at [CERN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CERN) or [Fermilab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermilab). Just instead of subatomic particles we're accelerating bigger (**much** bigger) objects.

Theoretically simething like this could be imaginable.

So why don't we build it?

- It takes a lot of energy
- The forces involved are huge
- it's really hard for protons to do already

So to keep the centrifugal forces in check we'd need to scale up the acelerator. Earth orbit probably won't help you much if you want to keep the g forces near any reasonable level. You'd need to go at least into an orbit around the sun. And you want your ring to be as close to circular as possible. So you basically need to build a structure that spans a whole orbit around the sun. This sounds like a *really* interesting engineering challenge. The nice thing is, that since you're already basically building a dyson sphere (or at least the ring part of it) you can use a sizeable portion of the energy output of the sun. This would catapult us to being close to a [Kardashev type II civilisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale#Type_II)

There are probably relativistic effects of big masses near the speed of light that need to be considered. I'm leaving that to people that understand more of that stuff to explain.

But all in all we can conclude that at our current (2022) technology level such a device can't be built by humankind.

Comment: Some quick math suggests built around the equator a 2G version (so you stand on the roof at 1G) gets you .0038% light speed. Built at Earth orbit distance it looks like limiting things to 1G gets you closer, but only 0.4% light speed. Even a ring beyond Pluto only gets 2.8% C. In a straight line a 1G push to 50% C seems to be 150 times the Sun-Pluto distance making all of these mega structures in their own right.

Comment: @GremlinWranger wow, thank you for that numbers! For me it would have been quite a bit more than "quick math". And that's all assuming a perfectly circular "orbit".

Comment: What about using natural planetary magnetic fields?

Comment: @Innovine how do you want to use them? What you need for an accelerator is a huge number of really strong magnets basically continious around the whole orbit very close to the payload. A planet is nothing of that. The magnetic field that some planets have is good enough to bend the path of subatomic particles (and to move the needle of a compas)... Not to bend the path of a spaceship significantly.